# SelectedIndexChange event handler code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am sort of stuck on the implementation.

I am using Windowsforms with Oracle db

I have a page with lot of controls including the `DropDownList` with subprograms (A,B, C..), a group of `CheckBoxes` and a yes/no `DropDown`.
On the top of the page there is a `DropDown` with a list of subprograms (A, B, C..) as mentioned above.

When A is selected from the `DropDown` the page should pull the existing data from the database, with the selected `CheckBoxes` and yes/no option selected
from the databse. Then the user can make any updates by changing or adding a few selections and then hit save button to navigate
to the next subprogram, B and then similar process repeats as above.

I have 2 questions here: 1. I am looking to code the `SelectedIndexChange` event handler with a functionality to pull the data from the database (I mean user
selections already made for `CheckBoxes` and `DropDown`

2. I have a `nextquestion_click` event handler: On clicking this after the end of all the subprograms the user should be able to navigate to the nextquestion.

Please provide me examples with sample code. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use .change() function of jQuery for dropdown. When user will change the index of dropdown then this function will be called. And you can use ajax to pull data from database.
2. for nextquestion_click event, you can use .click() function of button and on click even you can use ajax to pull the next question from database and display it.

Thanks,
Amit Prajapati